# Pattern match and sum values in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

I have a spreadsheet where users enter their three character name code corresponding to everyday with number of hours that they plan to spend in a specific task (A, B, C) within brackets. What I want is these needs to be summed up for every user and get populated in rows corresponding to their names everyday.

Currently I am using an custom vba function to perform this sum, however I wanted to know if this can be done directly with any custom formula or VLOOKUP. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: I have been using the function, one specific to each user (the three character code) to calculate this sum.

```
Function SumJON(Target As Range) As Double
Dim xCell As Range
Dim xSum As Double
xSum = 0

For Each xCell In Target
      If xCell.Value <> "" And InStr(xCell.Value, "JON") > 0 Then
      Test = Split(xCell.Value, "JON")
      Test1 = Test(1)
      Test2 = Split(Test1, ")")
      Test3 = Test2(0)
        xSum = xSum + Test3
      End If
Next

SumJON = xSum
End Function
```

Comment: And it's always the same pattern? Two names in a cell seperated through comma? And would these hours per task ever exceed 9? So basically would the number in brackets always just be one number?

Comment: That was a sample. There could be many such names inside a cell. Within the brackets, the numbers could have decimals.

Comment: On the surface, yes, it looks possible; but you say this is a sample, how well does it represent your actual data?  As your data grows, do you add more columns or rows?  Or do you continue adding more data to the same cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following, with the below setup of data:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID($A2,LEN($A2)-3,3),B$6:B$8)),MID(B$6:B$8,SEARCH(MID($A2,LEN($A2)-3,3),B$6:B$8)+4,SEARCH(")",B$6:B$8,SEARCH(MID($A2,LEN($A2)-3,3),B$6:B$8))-SEARCH(MID($A2,LEN($A2)-3,3),B$6:B$8)-4),0)*1)
```

> ***NOTE:*** This is an array formula and should be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag formula down and right.

---

It will also work on expending the amount of names in the list AND with decimals:

[image]

*Note that my system decimal point is a comma.*

---

Breakdown:

- To extract the searchvalue, `JON`, `DOE` and `PRK` we can make use of `MID` since you have a certain pattern to take into account. It would always have to be:

  ```
  =MID($A2,LEN($A2)-3,3)
  ```
- This value needs to be used in a `SEARCH` function which will return a position of our searchvalue in the `A,B,C` rows. Since it's an array formula it will return all these numeric positions or an error.
- Therefor we need to use `ISNUMBER` to check if the searchvalue is actually found through `SEARCH`. If so it will return a `TRUE` and if not it will return `FALSE`.
- Because this is part of our `IF`statement, the formula will do another `MID` function for the `TRUE` values. Again we will have to make use of our searchvalue formula, but this time we know it will be in these strings and therefor we can use the numerical position as our starting position (+4, because these strings are 3 positions long + the opening paranthesis) in this second `MID`.
- Now we have a starting position to get the lookupvalues from, we just need to know the first position of the next closing paranthesis, and we can do that through `SEARCH` from this exact position.
- Multiplying it by 1 in the end would turn these values in true numerical lookupvalues, which finally can be summed through `SUM`

Et voila, we got the total of values between the paranthesis where the searchcriteria meets the current user.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for! Could you please breakdown the formula and explain it a bit further?

Comment: @SiddharthArthi, please see edited answer. Hope you enjoy the formula.

Comment: Great. Thanks again. This is really helpful!